# Python installed at two locations

Tags: python

I installed Python for all users so I have my Python folder at the path `C:\Program Files\Python310`.

However, when I download any package I get warnings like

`WARNING: The scripts fonttools.exe, pyftmerge.exe, pyftsubset.exe and ttx.exe are installed in 'C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\Scripts' which is not on PATH.`

I noticed that I have another Python 310 folder at `C:\Users\aviba\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310`. I don't know how this is possible since I only installed Python once.

In envrionment variables:
`C:\Program Files\Python310\Scripts\`
`C:\Program Files\Python310\`

Should I completely uninstall Python and install it again to only my user? Or is there no problem here?

Comment: This is to check the python version `python --version` what does it output?

Comment: The `AppData` locations are necessary - do not delete them. They are part of the same installation. This is where packages are installed when you use the `--user` option for `pip`, or when the global `site-packages` isn't writeable. Do what it says and add `C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\Scripts` to your `PATH`.

Comment: Python 3.10.6 is the output

Comment: Also, try `where python` OR this `which python`

Comment: @MohamadGhaithAlzin read my first comment. It's all part of the same installation.

Comment: I added that path to envrionmental variables. But now will it get confused where Python is installed?

Comment: @MattDMo I added that path to enviornmental variables but I get the same warning when I installed another package

Comment: You need to restart your session where you're using `pip`. In fact, it would probably be better to just restart Windows. `PATH` changes aren't distributed to running programs.

Comment: Your computer is not going to get confused.

Comment: "Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable" Should I be paying attention to this message? I do not get the warnings anymore, but what does it mean for a global-site package to not be writable? Was I wrong to install Python to all users rather than my user?

Comment: My packages are now being installed at a different location (C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages) to where python is installed.